# HTML Email Clickable Address Link

Tags: email, html

I have a bit of a conundrum I was hoping the community could help me with. I'm developing a HTML email right now with physical address text (123 Main st. Citytown, Michigan 48484). I can certainly make it a clickable link to help improve the UX but that would force the user to go to a specific mapping service. I know some mobile devices automatically detect addresses and make them links to whatever default mapping software their system uses.

What would be the best course of action here? Should I force an href to a mapping service (Google Maps) on a physical address? Should I just leave it be and let people copy and paste the address to a mapping service? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leave the physical address unlinked and provide a [View map] link next to it. If the device is set up to link the address to its native mapping service, that will show up underlined. The "View map" link can go to a mapping service, for those who are viewing on desktop and devices that aren't linked.

Comment: Ah best both. I like it! Very creative.